# LEFT JOIN resulting in duplicate row - ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm writing a sub-query using a WITH clause, and joining it to a main query.
The main query has a result set of 332 records, and the sub-query has a result set of 302 records.
If I do a `LEFT JOIN` of the sub-query to the main query I would expect to get 332 but I'm getting 336.
I've checked both the main query and sub query for duplicates, specifically of the records being duplicated and duplicates do not exist in the queries independently, s why are they occurring in the join?

```
WITH FacOwner AS(
    SELECT 
        facility_id_fk, company,
        contact_first_name, contact_last_name,
        contact_title, contact_address1, contact_address2,
        contact_city, contact_state, contact_zipcode_five,
        contact_zipcode_four, contact_phone_number,
        
        sig_first_name, sig_last_name, 
        sig_title, sig_email,
        sig_address1, sig_address2, sig_city, sig_state, 
        sig_zipcode_five, sig_zipcode_four
        
        FROM Contacts
        WHERE Facility_Role = 'Owner'
)

SELECT 
    fg.facility_id_fk,
    fg.general_id_pk,
    fg.facility_name,
    fg.facility_status,
    fg.facility_type,
    fg.landfill_class,
    fg.dshw_staff_person,
    fg.ownership_type,
    loc.county,
    loc.facility_address_street,
    loc.facility_address_city,
    loc.health_department,
    
    FacOwner.company as Owner_Company, (FacOwner.contact_first_name || ' ' || FacOwner.contact_last_name) as OwnerName,  
    FacOwner.contact_title as OwnerTitle, (FacOwner.contact_address1 || FacOwner.contact_address2) as OwnerAddress,
    FacOwner.contact_city as OwnerCity, FacOwner.contact_state as OwnerState, (FacOwner.contact_zipcode_five || '-' || FacOwner.contact_zipcode_four) as OwnerZipcode,
    FacOwner.contact_phone_number as OwnerPhoneNumber,
    
    FacOwner.sig_first_name || ' ' || FacOwner.sig_last_name as OwnerCertSigName,
    FacOwner.sig_title as OwnerCertSigTitle, FacOwner.sig_email as OwnerCertSigEmail,
    (FacOwner.sig_address1 || ' ' || FacOwner.sig_address2) as OwnerCertSigAddress, FacOwner.sig_city as OwnerCertSigCity, FacOwner.sig_state as OwnerCertSigState, 
    (FacOwner.sig_zipcode_five || '-' || FacOwner.sig_zipcode_four) as OwnerCertSigZipcode

FROM facility_general fg
LEFT JOIN facility_location loc ON loc.facility_id_fk = fg.general_id_pk
LEFT JOIN FacOwner on FacOwner.facility_id_fk = fg.general_id_pk
ORDER BY fg.facility_id_fk;
```

Comment: The result set can be unique but may still have duplicates in the field you are joining on. Do count(*) and count(distinct ..) of the the columns involved in the joins in those 3 tables involved. The ones where those counts don't match could be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without representative data, I can only help you trouble shoot. To identify the problem, start with the following query.

Do all four columns return the same number?

```
WITH FacOwner AS(
    SELECT 
        facility_id_fk, company,
        contact_first_name, contact_last_name,
        contact_title, contact_address1, contact_address2,
        contact_city, contact_state, contact_zipcode_five,
        contact_zipcode_four, contact_phone_number,
        
        sig_first_name, sig_last_name, 
        sig_title, sig_email,
        sig_address1, sig_address2, sig_city, sig_state, 
        sig_zipcode_five, sig_zipcode_four
        
        FROM Contacts
        WHERE Facility_Role = 'Owner'
)
SELECT count(*), count(distinct fg.general_id_pk), 
count(distinct FacOwner.facility_id_fk),
count(distinct loc.facility_id_fk)
FROM facility_general fg
LEFT JOIN facility_location loc ON loc.facility_id_fk = fg.general_id_pk
LEFT JOIN FacOwner on FacOwner.facility_id_fk = fg.general_id_pk
ORDER BY fg.facility_id_fk;
```

Comment: Thanks @Skaugs - this is helpful. I got back 332 for distinct fg.general_id_pk which was to be expected but 298 for distinct facility owner.facility_id_fk. The results for facility owner have 302 so the 4 count difference probably explains why I'm gettign 336 (for more then expected) when I make the join). I'm going to look at the facility owners again get a count for id more that exist more then once.

Comment: I did a query to find facility contacts with a count greater then 1 and found the 4 duplicate records that I overlooked when scanning the full result set. Thanks!

Comment: A friend of mine once said that there are no mysteries in software development. I guess he was proven right again! Glad to be able to put you on the right track!